# vuetify v-radio doesn't select one radio in table nuxt js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to make a multiple grid radio with conditions: if one radio button is selected, save it as json with `key: question` and `value: column` where the radio button is selected.

```html
<template>
  <v-radio-group class="mt-0"
    v-model="answer"
    :rules="answerRule"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Pilihan</th>
        <th v-for="(option, keys) in columns" :key="keys + 'A'">
          {{ option.value }}
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr v-for="(option, keys) in rows" :key="keys + 'A'">
        <th>
          {{ option.value }}
        </th>
        <td v-for="(option, key) in columns" :key="key + 'B'">
          <v-radio-group
            v-model="answer"
            @change="update"
            :rules="answerRule"
          >
            <v-radio
              solo
              :key="key"
              :value="option.value"
            >
            </v-radio>
          </v-radio-group>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  </v-radio-group>
</template>
```

Here is my script on how to load the data and try to save the json:

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: ['question'],
  data() {
    return {
      rows: this.question.options,
      answer: [],
      columns: this.question.optionsColumns,
      answerRule: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async update() {
      try {
        let payload = {
          questionId: this.question.id,
          value: this.answer,
          questionName: this.question.question,
        }

        //update question options
        await this.$store.commit('answers/update', payload)
      } catch (err) {
        this.$store.commit('alerts/show', {
          type: 'error',
          message: err.response
            ? this.$t(err.response.data.message)
            : this.$t('SERVER_ERROR'),
        })
      }
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {
    if (this.question.required) {
      this.answerRule.push(
        (v) => v.length > 0 || this.$t('QUESTION_REQUIRED')
        )
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your question into something more readable. We don't have the shape of your data and there is quite some amount of code here. Do you mind debugging your app a bit initially thanks to some Vue devtools to see what is not working well here? What do you expect and what do you have as of right now? Overall, could you please put in a bit more effort as of what is not working?

Comment: hi kissu thanks for replying, actually i try to do the same as google form does for multiple grid radio button, it will target the row as the question and the column as the answer, what i expected is the answers in array of object like this 
answers:[ {"question 1":"answer 1}",{ "question 2":"ansswer 2}] which i cannot resolve it... @kis

Comment: @kissu hope it explained...

Comment: It's great, now we know what you want. Still, we need to know what you achieved so far and what is not working. Are you far from the structure that you provided? What is not working in that specific implementation? Your question is quite similar to this one btw: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74149694/8816585 And my advice is the same, focus on the JS part at first to understand how to shape your object/array properly from what you have until what you need. Then you'll be able to loop on it.

Comment: what i achieve so far is i only can select one value each row and each column, and cannot mapping out the key and value to be save as JSON...

Comment: Focus on that part first then: how to properly format your object/array.

Comment: uhm can you explained it more to me?.. @kissu

Comment: I can explain things but I'm not supposed to do everything for you for free. I'm not sure what is not understandable here. What do you want to do exactly? Keep it as a final result (the shape of your data). Then, start from what you have and try to use JS methods like `.map`, `.filter` etc to achieve your desired result. Don't use Vue initially, figure out how to make things properly in JS before proceeding with Vue. I don't know the shape of your data and it would be a nice exercise for you to try to put in a bit more effort here. SO is not a free coding platform.